# DJI Android-UXSDKDemo Mavic 2 Enterprise turns to north

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Im using the latest UX SDK 4.12 on Android with DJI MAVIC 2 enterprise.
I upload 2 WayPoints in a WayPointMission. The aircraft is heading in the direction of the flight:
WaypointMissionHeadingMode.AUTO
Once the last waypoint is reached, I send startShootPhoto command to take a single photo.

For some strange reason, the aircraft turns to the absolute north or west north before taking the photo and then turns back to the original heading position.

Can any one please suggest how to keep the aircraft heading in the same direction when taking the photo?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following attributes to control the Flight Orientation and it solved the problem. It seems that camera was not the one causing the aircraft to turn.

```
aircraft.getFlightController().setFlightOrientationMode(FlightOrientationMode.AIRCRAFT_HEADING, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
        Log.i(TAG, "FlightOrientationMode " + djiError);
    }
});

WaypointMissionHeadingMode mHeadingMode = WaypointMissionHeadingMode.AUTO;
waypointMissionBuilder = new WaypointMission.Builder().finishedAction(mFinishedAction)
                    .headingMode(mHeadingMode)
                    .autoFlightSpeed(SPEED)
                    .maxFlightSpeed(SPEED)
                    .flightPathMode(WaypointMissionFlightPathMode.NORMAL);
```